# Ruby character encoding for shreelipi Indian devenagari font

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am new to Ruby and I'm trying to write a script (Ruby 1.9.3, on Windows XP) which will automate text extraction from an InDesign document using the WIN32OLE library.

The InDesign document has text in ShreeLipi font (an Indian Devanagari script). My Ruby script is:

require 'win32ole'

```
app = WIN32OLE.new('InDesign.Application')
doc = app.activeDocument
text_frame = doc.textFrames(1)
text = text_frame.contents #=> "emhy ‘hmamOm§Mo ñ‘maH$ emhy {‘b‘Ü¶o C^mam"
puts text.encoding.name #=> "IBM437"
file = File.open('D:/try.txt','w')
file.puts text
file.close
```

When I open this same file to view the text using Notepad it shows:

```
"emhy `hmamOmMo ¤`maH$ emhy {`b`šo C^mam"
```

I can't understand why this is happening. Please help me correct it.
I tried to resolve it using Windows-1252 encoding and also with ISO-8859-1 but could not find a solution.

Comment: You do understand that fonts are not the same as encodings, right? The encoding is how Ruby interprets a stream of binary data. The font is how your OS lights up pixels on the display for your eyes to see based on that stream of binary data. They're very separate things, at very different levels, and Ruby doesn't know, or care, about fonts.

Comment: Thank for your reply! You said it correct that font and encoding are different things. My concern is why the characters are changing after writing it to file. I am expecting that it should be same as it was. Am I missing something to consider on?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't preserving your bytes when you write the file. Instead of doing:

```
file = File.open('D:/try.txt','w')
```

use:

```
file = File.open('D:/try.txt','wb')
```

The `b` means to write as binary, which, in plain English, means to do no line-end conversions.